# How to show $f(x_1,x_2)=\begin{pmatrix} e^{x_1}+e^{x_2} \\ e^{x_1}-e^{x_2} \end{pmatrix}$ is surjective?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse

Let $f: R^2 \to R^2$ be

$f(x_1,x_2)=\begin{pmatrix} e^{x_1}+e^{x_2} \\ e^{x_1}-e^{x_2} \end{pmatrix}$

I am trying to show it is invertible. So far I have shown it is injective, but I still need to show it is surjective. My understanding is that $f: R^2 \to A$ is surjective if the range of $f$ is the whole of $A$, therefore I would need to redefine the codomain to get global invertibility. Is this correct? How would you show surjectivity?

Comment: All you have to do is show that for all $a,b$ there exists $x,y$ such that $e^x+e^y=a,e^x-e^y=b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\begin{pmatrix} e^{x_1}+e^{x_2} \\ e^{x_1}-e^{x_2} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} \implies 2e^{x_1}=a+b \quad \land \quad 2e^{x_2}=a-b$$

and now, what about if $a+b\le0 \lor a-b\le 0$?

Then we need $a+b>0$ and $a-b >0$.

Comment: So $f$ is not surjective on $f:R^2 \to R^2$ but on $f:R^2 \to S$, where $S=\{(a,b):a+b>0, a-b>0\}$?

Comment: @econ86 Yes it is surjectiv in the restriction $a+b>0$ and $a-b>0$.

Comment: And therefore it is globally invertible, correct? (given injectivity)

Comment: @econ86 Yes if it is also injective.

Answer (score 1):

The function is certainly not surjective. The image contains only points whose first coordinate is positive.

Comment: Beat me to it by 30 seconds!

Comment: Right, so I need to redefine the codomain so that it is surjective there, i.e. $f:R^2 \to S$, where $S=\{(a,b):a+b>0, a-b>0\}$ as in the comment by @gimusi. Then $f$ (redefined) would be globally invertible. Is this correct?

Comment: If the function is injective and surjective, then, yes, it is invertible.